# The GET method is not supported when redirecting back in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to redirect the user back to the previous page if the token entered is invalid  but i'm getting the error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Everything works well when the token is valid. Here  is my code:

**ForgotPasswordController**

```
public function showPasswordResetForm(Request $request)
{
    $inputToken = $request->token;
    $tokenData = DB::table('password_resets')
                    ->where('token', $inputToken)
                    ->first();

    if ( ! $tokenData) {
      return redirect()
            ->back()
            //redirect back if the token does not exist  
            ->withErrors(['token' => 'Token doesnt exist']);
    } 

    $token = $tokenData->token;

    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with('token', $token);
}
```

Route

```
 Route::get('reset-password/{token}', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showPasswordResetForm')
        ->name('check.token');
```

Blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('check.token',$token) }}">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="token" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
            {{ __('Reset code') }}
        </label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input 
                id='token'
                type="text"
                class="form-control @error('token') is-invalid @enderror" 
                name="token" 
                required 
                autocomplete="token"  
                autofocus
            >

            @error('token')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Continue') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `Route::get` only accepts `GET` requests but your form uses `<form method="POST"`

Comment: I have tried to change to `<form method="GET"`  but still showing `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST` @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are sending data through a form, you should avoid using `GET` (as the one defined in your route). You are making a post request, so this must be consistent with your defined endpoint. Chage it to this:

```
/** view */

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('check.token', $token) }}">
    //       ^^^^^
</form>

/** route */

Route::post('reset-password/{token}', '/** ... */')->name('check.token');
//     ^^^^
```

Now, the error is originated when doing the redirect back, this doesn't have to do with this endpoint but **the previous one, the one that shows that form**. It looks like this previous endpoint is defined as `POST` instead of `GET`, this is the one that you should modify to fix the issue.

We can't see how this route is defined so I'll use an example. Try changing it from:

```
Route::post('show-form', 'MyController@myMethod');
```

To this:

```
Route::get('show-form', 'MyController@myMethod');
```